# Finding values based on array index in List<string[]>

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list

I have an array structured like this:

```
{"nick", "sender", "message"}
```

arranged into a `List<string[]>`.

What I want to do, is to search the list using the 0 index value of the array (ie nick).

I tried using:

```
list.Find(i => i[0].Equals(nick))
```

but this doesn't seem to do anything.

How would I do this?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean.. why would you only want to search the first index position? Surely you would just do if(i[0] == nick) for that?

Comment: so I have a whole slew of values in this list, with lots of different nick values. this is for a memo system of sorts, so I want to retrieve every array from the list with the index 0 value equal to the nick i'm after.

so, for example:
{"sue", "bob", "dinner at 9"}
{"joe", "bob", "park your car"}
{"sue", "joe", "bob smells"}

and I want the list to return the values which have the value "sue" in index 0

Comment: Try this: `list.Find(i => i[0] == "nick");`.

Comment: What about using list.Where(i => i[0] == nick) then to get a list of string[] that contain nick at first index?

Comment: Your code works fine for me. (provided nick variable contains "nick").

Comment: Why are you using arrays like that? Wouldn't it be wiser to write a struct representing a message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this what you want

```
list.Where(i => i[0] == "nick")
```

It will return a `IEnumerable<string[]>` where nick if the first element in each `string[]`

Comment: This also works - though my original code turned out to be okay, displaying it elsewhere was the issue!

Answer (score 0):

```
 list.Where(x => x[0].Equals(nick));
```

Comment: @Gilad power of suggestion in question ;)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're after:-

```
list.Find(i => i.Equals("nick"))
```

I'm also guessing that this isn't what you mean....

Perhaps you have something more like this:-

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new List<string[]>() {
                                            new String[3] { "a", "b", "b" }, 
                                            new String[3] { "a", "c", "c" }, 
                                            new String[3] { "b", "b", "c" }, 
                                            new String[3] { "a", "d", "d" }, 
                                            new String[3] { "x", "y", "z" } 
                                        };
        var foundFirst = test.Find(i => i[0].Equals("a"));
        var foundAll = test.Where(i => i[0].Equals("a"));
    }
```